# Calculating Spearman Correlation from scratch

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, homework, statistics

Over the week, I was assigned to create a function in a Jupyter notebook that satisfies the Spearman Correlation formula without the use of any packages e.g. Numpy, Pandas. Below are the rules of the game, followed by solution.

I am seeking any input on how this could be done more efficiently.

> The Spearman rank correlation is used to evaluate if the relationship between two variables, X and Y is monotonic. The rank correlation measures how closely related the ordering of one variable to the other variable, with no regard to the actual values of the variables.
> To calculate the Spearman rank correlation for \$X\$ and \$Y\$, \$ρ_S(X, Y)\$:
>
> - the values of \$X\$ and \$Y\$ are ranked in an ascending order respectively. The smallest value will be given a rank of 1, the next smaller value will be given a rank of 2, etc. If there are multiple entries with the same value, then each entry is ranked equal to the average position.
> - the rank difference for the i-th pair of \$x_i\$ and \$y_i\$ is then calculated and,
>   $$
>   \rho_S(X, Y) = 1 - \frac{6\sum_{i=1}^{N} d_i^2}{N(N^2-1)}
>   $$
>   where \$N\$ is the total pairs of data points and \$d_i\$ is the rank difference for the i-th pair of data.
>
> Create a function `calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(X, Y)` that returns you the value of the rank correlation, given two sets of data `X` and `Y`.

My solution:

```
def calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(X,Y):
    '''
    #The Spearman rank correlation is used to evaluate if the relationship between two variables, 
    X and Y is monotonic. The rank correlation measures how closely related the ordering of one
    variable to the other variable, with no regard to the actual values of the variables. 
    '''
    if len(X) != len(Y): #Making sure length is the same
        return("Please check your dataset again for input errors.") 
    else:
        # for X
        xranks = [sorted(X).index(x) + 1 for x in X]
        dupesx = [x for n, x in enumerate(xranks) if x in xranks[:n]]
        if len(dupesx) == 0: 
            print(xranks)
        else:
            
            dupenumberx = dupesx[0]
            count_ax = xranks.count(dupesx[0])
        
            sumx = 0
            tx = 0
            while tx < count_ax:
                sumx = sumx + dupenumberx + 1*tx
                tx=tx+1
                sumx2 = sumx/count_ax
                for i in range(len(xranks)):
                    if xranks[i] == dupenumberx:
                        xranks[i] = sumx2
                        
        # for Y
        yranks = [sorted(Y).index(y) + 1 for y in Y]
        dupesy = [y for n, y in enumerate(yranks) if y in yranks[:n]]
        if len(dupesy) == 0: 
            print(yranks)
        else:
            
            dupenumbery = dupesy[0]
            count_ay = yranks.count(dupesy[0])
        
            sumy = 0
            ty = 0
            while ty < count_ay:
                sumy = sumy + dupenumbery + 1*ty
                ty=ty+1
                sumy2 = sumy/count_ay
                for i in range(len(yranks)):
                    if yranks[i] == dupenumbery:
                        yranks[i] = sumy2
        

        # calculate rank difference for the i-th pair of data
        sub_list = []
        zip_object = zip(xranks, yranks)
        for xranks_i, yranks_i in zip_object:
            sub_list.append(xranks_i - yranks_i)
            
        # inplementing the formula for SRC
        sub_list2 = [i **2 for i in sub_list]
        di = sum(sub_list2)
        N = len(X)
        SRC = (1 - (6 * (di))/(N*((N**2)-1)))
        SRC_1dp = round(SRC, 3)
    return "The Spearman rank correlation is", SRC_1dp
```

The test sets:

```
# test case a
Xa = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Ya = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(Xa,Ya)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
('The Spearman rank correlation is', 1.0)
```

---

test:

```
# test case b
Xb= [10, 20, 20, 50, 40]
Yb= [2, 10, 6, 4, 8]
calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(Xb,Yb)
```

output:

```
[1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
('The Spearman rank correlation is', -0.45)
```

---

test:

```
# test case d
Xd= [50, 50, 50, 30, 30, 30]
Yd= [2, 10, 8, 6, 10, 10]
calculate_spearman_rank_correlation(Xd,Yd)
```

output:

```
 ('The Spearman rank correlation is', 0.883)
```

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong, since you only ever average the first dupe, but not all.

Comment: @RichardNeumann In this case I (barely) disagree with closing this; see also [Why was this question closed as off-topic after a bug was discovered by the answers?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7113/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-after-a-bug-was-discovered-by-the-answ). If OP didn't understand that there was a bug upon posting, and if that bug doesn't occur for the central use case of a series with unique values, and since the thrust of the question is genuinely review and not bug fixing, I see no harm in keeping it open.

Answer (score 3):

@RichardNeumann correctly points out that your implementation does not adhere to the specification you were given. You've written test cases - good! But the missing step is that you haven't validated your results against a known implementation of the algorithm, such as that at [Social Science Statistics](https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/spearman/default2.aspx).

Do not return error message strings; raise an exception.

You should factor out a rank calculation function rather than copying and pasting for X and Y.

Aside from the rank calculation, you don't have to do any of the statistics yourself. You say you don't want to use any "packages": fine; the built-in module `statistics` is not a package.

Write unit tests via `assert`.

### Suggested

```py
from collections import Counter
from math import isclose
from statistics import stdev, covariance
from typing import Sequence, Iterator


def rank_series(values: Sequence[float]) -> Iterator[float]:
    rank_by_value = {}
    index = 0
    for x, n in sorted(Counter(values).items()):
        rank_by_value[x] = index + (1 + n)/2
        index += n
    for x in values:
        yield rank_by_value[x]


def calculate_spearman(x: Sequence[float], y: Sequence[float]) -> float:
    """
    The Spearman rank correlation is used to evaluate if the relationship between two variables,
    X and Y is monotonic. The rank correlation measures how closely related the ordering of one
    variable to the other variable, with no regard to the actual values of the variables.
    """
    if len(x) != len(y):
        raise ValueError(f'X length {len(x)} does not match Y length {len(y)}')

    x_ranks = tuple(rank_series(x))
    y_ranks = tuple(rank_series(y))
    covxy = covariance(x_ranks, y_ranks)
    stdx = stdev(x_ranks)
    stdy = stdev(y_ranks)
    r = covxy / stdx / stdy
    return r


def test(x: Sequence[float], y: Sequence[float], expected: float) -> None:
    r = calculate_spearman(x, y)
    assert isclose(r, expected, abs_tol=0, rel_tol=1e-6)


def test_all() -> None:
    test(
        (10, 20, 20, 50, 40),
        (2, 10, 6, 4, 8),
        0.20519567041703082,
    )
    test(
        (10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
        (2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
        1,
    )
    test(
        (50, 50, 50, 30, 30, 30),
        (2, 10, 8, 6, 10, 10),
        -0.3110855084191276,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_all()
```